# How do I simplify this templated vector initializer loop using lambdas or STL transform?

Tags: c++, templates, stl, vector, c++11

How do I simplify this templated vector initializer loop using lambdas or some kind of STL transform?

```
template<typename T>
template<typename... Args>
void InitToRandomValues(vector<T>* retval, int n, RNG& rng, Args const&... args) {
    retval->resize(n);
    for (auto it = retval->begin(); it != retval->end(); ++it) {
        typename T::CPDDist cpd(rng, args...);
        *it = T(cpd);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can write the entire thing in one statement. You don't need to pass `n` to get the size of the list, either. `sizeof...(Args)` can be used instead. `*retval = { (args, typename T::CPDDist(rng, args...))... };`

Comment: Okay, I just edited the question so that the class definition and myBasis are replaced with a vector pointer -- should make it easier.

I will try:

retval = vector<T>({ (args, typename T::CPDDist(rng, args...))... });

and then come back to say whether it worked.

Comment: where is the "n" parameter being used in that solution?  It compiles, but I only get two elements.

Comment: I also tried *retval = vector<T>(n, (typename T::...));

This calls the function once and sets every element to that value.  I think we need some kind of lambda.

Comment: @Neil it isn't used, because i asssumed you just pass `n` to know how many elements follow. If that's not the case, my comment won't work. (also, are you restricted to use lambdas and transform, or will other solutions be fine too, if they work?). Can you comment on the meaning of `n`?

Comment: @Neil also what's wrong with `retval->resize(n, typename T::CPDDist(rng, args...));` ?

Comment: @Johannes, the `n` parameter is used in the function's first statement to *set* the length of the vector.

Comment: T::CPDDist(rng, args...))

generates a random instance of CPPDDist (RNG is a non-const random number generator), so this invocation will return n identical elements.

Comment: Rob figured out what I meant: n is the desired number of vector elements.  The reason for the parameter pack is because different T's (distributions) need different numbers of elements to be randomly initialized.

Comment: @Neil ooh i see now. oO must have been blind. Thanks for elaborating on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this would work:

```
template<typename T>
template<typename... Args>
void InitToRandomValues(vector<T>* retval, int n, RNG& rng, Args const&... args) {
    retval->resize(n);
    std::generate(retval->begin(), retval->end(), [] -> T() {
        typename T::CPDDist cpd(rng, args...);
        return T(cpd); });
}
```

It isn't much of a simplification though.

Comment: Yea, but it's probably the best that can be done though.  I'll give the question another half hour and then mark this as best if nothing is better.

Comment: GCC4.5 adds lambda syntax. 4.4 doesn't have it.